# Constructing dependencies and performing DI in c++

Tags: c++, oop, dependency-injection

What are the best practices for performing dependency injection in real c++ applications.
Say that my application starts in class A, which creates class B. class B depends on class C, which depends on class D (and so on). 
Who should be responsible for creating class C and class D?

Comment: This is barely related to c++

Comment: Please don't cross post http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/233819/injecting-dependencies-di-in-c-applications

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like A is your [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot), so it should have the responsibility of creating and composing all the other objects.

Comment: Should A just create D, use it to create B and use B to create A? Are there any better practices? Maybe i should use a builder or factory?

Comment: Just build the graph: if you use Constructor Injection, there's only one way to build the graph. Here are some examples: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence